# mySQL Eclipse JSP unable to insert

Tags: mysql, eclipse, sql-insert

I have a problem inserting data into my sweet little database. It aint so sweet in my eyes anymore though...
I am able to select data from the mysql-database but for some wierd reason I am not able to insert data.

I use Eclipse EE, mySql-worbench and Tomcat as a local server.
I am experimenting with the sakila database which is one of the standard/preview databases i mySQL.

Its a very simple small program, since I am very new to these elements and still learning.
At some points (not always) the system out println in the SQLException catch says unable to connect to database.

Here is the code I am working on:
http://pastebin.com/DsQwQPPZ

Here is a proof that I have connection with my database:
http://pbrd.co/1rrcZpr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, syntax was wrong! 
When doing a select I did not have to write the databases name, but when doing a insert or delete this was required.